# MSSQL and PDO very slow

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, cakephp-2.3

I am looking for a solution for this since days. Found nothing that worked...

I am working on a (cake) php application.
On my local machine, I have a mysql database. When i connect to this database, my queries are fast.

When I execute the same code on the server, which is a Microsoft Server 2008 with MSSQL, my queries are really slow.

Here a little test which specifies the problem best:

```
$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);

$dsn = 'sqlsrv:server=127.0.0.1;Database=xxx_art_collection';
$user = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';

$start_time=microtime(true);
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $attrs);

    $statement = $dbh->prepare("select * from items where id<10000");
    $statement->execute();

    //$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //print_r($rows);

    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row['id']);
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$stop_time=microtime(true);
print_r('<br />'.number_format($stop_time-$start_time,4));
```

I have about 1000 entries and my measured time is around 50 seconds....
On mysql its about 0.1 seconds...

Thanks for an help...

Comment: Is the `items.id` column indexed? It should be, and then you should make use of it in a way like `SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC`. MSSQL and MySQL are quite different internally, you need to take that into account.

Comment: `select top 10000` does not mean the same thing as `where id < 10000`, since rows can be deleted. @Sammitch is probably right, though, that the most likely cause of the slowness is a missing index.

Comment: Quick! [Open up SSMS!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) Paste in the query and, enable "Include Actual Execution Plan", then run the query - problem identified (or a source eliminated) in mere seconds! If there is a grossly missing index, SSMS will even display a friendly reminder indicating such.

Comment: See my comment below....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no physical problem with the connection to the MSSQL server (low latency, network issues, etc) and that there is nothing wrong with the PDO driver, there should no be such a big difference.

As @Sammitch said you should index the item.id field. Also try the WITH (NOLOCK) hint. 
Something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  items i WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
  i.id < 10000
```

Comment: In SSMS the query is very fast. So probably its a network issue. What is the best strategy to find the solution.

Comment: I can see you are connecting to MSSQL locally so it shouldn't not be network problem. I assume that from kyour connection string from PDO. If not try doing a traceroute and see how many hops, or packet loss you have. Also remember one thing, if the amount of data being transmitted on the network is to large, it may also slow things down.
You problem only exists with that particular table, or in all of them?
SQL Server Management Studio issues some commands to the server that we don't actually see them, there may some hint we are missing here.

Comment: Made some further invenstigation:
Database Server is local: When I use the same script to execute a query on a Mysql databsae (same data), its also very slow. If I execute the script locally on my computer (OSX, MySQL, MAMPP, same data), its fast. The server is on vmware... Probably that is causing the problem. Or windows ecurity? Or ...?

Comment: Probably both.... 
It's hard to tell now.
Since your server is on a virtual machine it could be the network configuration of the machine, the resources it has allocated, the network interface between windows and vmware and even the windows security features...

Comment: Can you give me a hint or a strategy on how to find the problem... Or how to exclude some stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you can execute the query on the vmachine, and it's fast its not a resource issue. Try downloading a file from your virtual machine to your desktop for example. This way you can benchmark your network.. I am not very familiar with vmware so i cant help you that much... Im more a virtual box guy...
But it all points to a network issue!